# Set different default browsers for 3G and Wifi

Tags: browser

I use Opera Mini when on 3G, and Firefox when on WiFi. Is there a way to set them as default? I have a custom 4.3 ROM and Tasker, if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, *Tasker* is the key here. You can find a tutorial here: [Control which app is the default for an action](http://www.pocketables.com/2013/07/quick-tasker-tip-switch-which-app-is-the-default-for-an-action-root-only.html).

In addition to *Tasker*, you will need the [Secure Settings plug-in](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin). The action involved which can be found there is called *Package State*, where you can select between disable, enable, and toggle. So basically it is a work-around: You disable *Firefox* when switching to 3G, so only *Opera* is available then and will be used. As soon as you switch to WiFi (*Tasker* condition: *WIFI connected*), you toggle both package states, so *Firefox* becomes the default browser as it's the only one available.

Comment: That's my second question you've answered with Tasker. I see you love yourself some Tasker hehe :)